# Heroku Technical Details

Tags: node.js, heroku, paas

What are the specs of the VMs that Heroku runs? One of my binary executable is not working (works perfectly fine on my computer), and I think it may be due to technical mismatches.

When I run `file` on my executable, I get `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`.

- Does Heroku use a 64 bit machine with x86 architecture?
- What kind of nix do they use?
- What other reasons would there be for an (C++) executable executing fine in my app locally, but not on Heroku itself?

The error I get is gibberish:

```
2014-09-07T04:38:32.909511+00:00 app[web.1]: ./process: 1: �����#�
                                                                  ��!H__PAGEZERO�__TEXT�__text__TEXT�a�d�a�__stubs__TEXT: not found
2014-09-07T04:38:32.909519+00:00 app[web.1]: ./process: 3: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
2014-09-07T04:38:32.909521+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-07T04:38:32.909517+00:00 app[web.1]: ./process: 2: ��: not found
```

Comment: `uname -a` yields `Linux ba17bfc1-7112-4859-a6a9-b33b6fff8eea 3.8.11-ec2 #6 SMP Tue Jul 22 22:02:15 UTC 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux` so what would the problem be then?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku apps are deployed on their [Cedar Stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar) which is based on a 64-bit Ubuntu 10.04.  The new Cedar-14 stack is based on Ubuntu 14.04.

By deploying a simple Node.js app and using `heroku run bash` we can inspect the live environment:

```
$ heroku run bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.2785

~ $ which node
/app/vendor/node/bin/node

~ $ file /app/vendor/node/bin/node
/app/vendor/node/bin/node: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped

~ $ uname -a
Linux 9cf0ac66-9131-4a19-8f4a-f4a132cf3db8 3.8.11-ec2 #6 SMP Tue Jul 22 22:02:15 UTC 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It's important to note that Heroku is *not* designed to run pre-compiled executables.  Rather, it is designed to compile your application as part of the build stage of [Heroku Buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks).

For more detail, take a look at the "Build, release, run" section of [The Twelve Factor App](http://12factor.net/build-release-run) -- a set of application best practices you must follow to use a PaaS like Heroku.